# Creating a Full-Text Search in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to relalize full-text search in flask, but nothing happend, there is nothing in traceback and web-application keep working. Please, could you advise me, where I should make some corrections, I try to realize this one first time and dont have such experience before.

**event\forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    query = StringField('search', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"class": "form-control"})
    submit = SubmitField('Submit', render_kw={'class': 'btn btn-secondary border-0'})
```

**event\models.py**

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['title', 'description']
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    genre = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_start = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=True)
    date_finish = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    place = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    price = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref='events')
    resource_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('resource.id'))
    resource = db.relationship('Resource', backref='events')
```

**event\views.py**

```
@blueprint.before_request
def before_request():
    g.search_form = SearchForm()

@blueprint.route('/search', methods = ['POST'])
def search():
    if not g.search_form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('event.index'))
    return redirect(url_for('event.search_results', query = g.search_form.search.data))

@blueprint.route('/search_results/<query>')
def search_results(query):
    search_str = f"%{form.search.data}%"
    results = Event.query.filter(Event.name.ilike(search_str), Event.description.ilike(search_str))
    return render_template('event/search_results.html',
        query = query,
        results = results)
```

**event\search_results.html**

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if results %}
    <h3>Here are some results</h3>
    
        {% for result in results %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('event.search_results') }}" class="list-group-item">{{ result }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues.

1. On the '/search_results/' route, form.search.data is never defined. Since you included that as a url parameter, you can reference "query" directly in your sqlalchemy query.
2. The filter clause on your query is currently:
   `filter(Event.name.ilike(search_str), Event.description.ilike(search_str))`
   which translates to name *and* description are both like search_str.  I'm assuming that you what you are really looking for is name *or* description are like search_str.

If that's the case, you can wrap the filter with an "or" clause.
`filter(or_(Event.name.ilike(search_str), Event.description.ilike(search_str)))`
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_